# SELECT clause against values from array

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing the column regions

```
create unlogged table dump
(
    id                                  varchar not null,
    regions                             citext default '[]'::text,
);
```

Need to perform a search query on the table returning all the values containing India and united kingdom

Row can contain any number of values, I need rows wherein regions array both india and united kingdom are present

Sample output using select query

```
SELECT regions from test_dump where regions IS NOT NULL
```

```
{"pennsylvania, united states","michigan, united states"}
{}
{"new york, united states"}
{"act, australia"}
{}
{"vermont, united states"}
{"vermont, united states"}
{"ontario, canada"}
{"colorado, united states","ontario, canada"}
{"kwazulu-natal, south africa","new south wales, australia"}
{"kwazulu-natal, south africa","new south wales, australia"}
{"greater london, united kingdom","surrey, united kingdom"}
{"madrid, spain"}
{"illinois, united states"}
{}
{"punjab, india","ontario, canada"}
{"veneto, italy"}
{"maharashtra, india"}
{"midtjylland, denmark"}
{"ohio, united states","indiana, united states"}
{"massachusetts, united states"}
```

Comment: To your question add example data for the values that you are trying to find.

Comment: This doesn't look like PostgreSQL, but rather some unspecified ORM that might eventually be turned into PostgreSQL.  Please describe your table with a `CREATE TABLE` statement, not with an unspecified ORM.

Comment: You really should use `citext[]` as the column type. Or possibly even `ltree[]`.

Comment: @Bergi I can't really make such an update at this point, the table has over 100M records. I didn't create the table, in future when I have authorization will update it. The type should have been _text

Answer (score 0):

Expand the array to a row set using unnest() function:

```
SELECT *
  FROM <table>
 WHERE
EXISTS
     ( SELECT 1
         FROM unnest(<value_column>)
           AS a(value)
        WHERE a.value ilike '%india'     
     )
   AND
EXISTS
     ( SELECT 1
         FROM unnest(<value_column>)
           AS a(value)
        WHERE a.value ilike '%united kingdom'     
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution:

**UPDATED** to include data in comment from @smvenk and change to query to address.

```
select id, varchar_array from array_test ;
 id |                     varchar_array                     
----+-------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"florida, united states"}
  2 | {"texas, united states"}
  3 | {"ohio, united states","north dakota, united states"}
  4 | {"london, united kingdom","mumbai, india"}
  5 | {"indiana, united states","wales, united kingdom"}


SELECT
    id,
    array_val
FROM
    array_test,
    array_to_string(varchar_array, ',') AS un (array_val)
WHERE
    array_val ILIKE '%, india%'
    AND array_val ILIKE '%, united kingdom%';

id |              array_val               
----+--------------------------------------
  4 | london, united kingdom,mumbai, india
```

From here [Array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

> array_to_string ( array anyarray, delimiter text [, null_string text ] ) → text

> Converts each array element to its text representation, and concatenates those separated by the delimiter string. If null_string is given and is not NULL, then NULL array entries are represented by that string; otherwise, they are omitted.

> array_to_string(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, NULL, 5], ',', '*') → 1,2,3,*,5

This pulls all the separate values into a single string which is then searched for `india` and the `united kingdom`.

Comment: {"indiana, united states", "wales, united kingdom"}

Comment: That could be solved by: `...ilike '%, india%' and array_val ilike '%, united kingdom%'`. A complete solution awaits the OP providing more example data, especially that for the values being searched for.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver added query examples for clarity

Comment: Have tried mine and @smvenk solutions to see if they work?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the solution in the answer had type casting issues, did end up using the following



```
SELECT count(id) from test_dump WHERE regions ILIKE '%, india%' and regions ILIKE '%, united kingdom%'
```

Comment: Then `regions` is not actually an array field.